# Using the constructor of the base class when creating new object of derived class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

```
    Public class A
    {
    ...
    }
    Public class B:A
    {
    ...
    }
    Public class Prog
    {
    public static void Main()
    {
         A myA = new B();
    }
}
```

If myA is an instance of A class, why I use B constructor, and how it differ from this:

```
A myA = new A();
```

also this code may be closer to this issue:
[image]

I know this may be very basic question, but I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the `B` constructor, only if you want an instance of `B` that inherits `A`.

You can also setup `B` so that is calls the constructor of `A` for you, eg:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

It all entirely depends on the implementation of your `A` and `B` classes and what you want to use them for.

Edit:

In light of your image, the reason you are calling like `Vehicle c = new Car()` is because the object you are actually creating is a `Car` but you still want or need to use aspects of the base class. Having this base class means you can have common properties between implementing classes.

For example:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
    }

    public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car() : base()
    {
        NumberOfWheels = 4;
    }
}

public class Motorbike : Vehicle
{
    public Motorbike() : base()
    {
        NumberOfWheels = 2;
    }
}
```

This case allows you to only define `NumberOfWheels` once and just set the value appropriately for the implementation you are writing. You can do the same thing with methods using `virtual` methods.

Comment: I've added a photo of more advanced example, please take a look.

Comment: You say: ".. you still want or need to use aspects of the base class."
But the derived class can already access the members of the base class, isn't it? then why extending a feature that is already exists??

Comment: Because the *values* of that feature may be different. It also means you are defining a contract that all implementing classes have to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
A myA = new B();
```

This is creating an object of type `B`. It is *not* creating an object of type `A`. *However*, you are [casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) the object to `A`. Casting in layterms essentially means you are saying 'View this object as if it were an `A`. Ignore the fact that it may be a `B`. Only show me methods and properties which were defined in the class `A`).

Note that you can re-cast it back to `B`, which does not change the object whatsoever:

```
B myB = (B)myA;
```

The difference between this:

```
A myA = new A();
```

and this:

```
A myA = new B();
```

Is that the first statement is creating a physical object of type `A`. Any overrides or new method/properties/fields defined in `B` *will not be created*.  The second statement will create a physical object of type `B`, but to *view* it (even temporarily) as an `A`

Comment: I've added a photo of more advanced example, please take a look.